# Tab \t not working in php

Tags: php

When using PHP:

```
<?php
//coba spasi atau tab
$matrix=array(array(0.4444444,0.25,3),
              array(0.62,0.5,5.33),
              array(2,0.91,3.333333333)
);
//print_r($matrix);
foreach($matrix as $baris){
    foreach($baris as $bar){
        echo round($bar,4)."\t";
    }
    echo '<br>';
} ?>
```

I get the following:

[image]

When I use CSS:

```
echo round($bar,4).'<span style="display: inline-block; width: 60px;"></span>';
```

The result:

[image]

I want the result like this:

```
0.4444    0.25    3
0.62      0.5     5.33
2         0.91    3.3333
```

Comment: You can do this with `sprintf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
echo round($bar,4).'<span style="display: inline-block; width: 60px;"></span>';
```

to

```
echo '<span style="display: inline-block; width: 60px;">'.round($bar,4).'</span>';
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the issue. He is wanting the columns to be aligned and this doesn't align them, it just spaces it with even spaces

Answer (score 4):

Add **pre** tag before the loop

```
echo '<pre>';

foreach ( $matrix as $baris ) {

    foreach ( $baris as $bar ) {
        echo round( $bar, 4 ) . '\t';
    }

    echo '<br>';

}

echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 3):

You should just use a `<table>`, this is **exactly** what a `<table>` is meant for.

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace, including tabs, is collapsed in HTML.

You either need to wrap all the output in a `<pre>` tag, or use the `white-space: pre;` CSS property.

In your case, a `<table>` might be more advisable.